# Predict using a linear model in R, given data points

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, predict

I have set up the model:

```
selected.model<-(ES~Area+Elevation+DistSC+I(Elevation^2)+
                 (Elevation*DistSC)+(Area*Elevation))
```

I want to predict ES given the data points:

```
Area=0.02, Anear=58.27, Dist=27.1, DistSC=65, Elevation=60
```

Anear and Dist are not required.

However I get an error when I try use predict, can anyone help?

```
predict(selected.model, newdata=data.frame(Area=0.02, Elevation=60, DistSC=65))
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "formula"
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually fit the model.

This:

```
selected.model<-(ES~Area+Elevation+DistSC+I(Elevation^2)+
                 (Elevation*DistSC)+(Area*Elevation))
```

simply creates a formula object. Linear models are created in R using the `lm` command. Which you can read about by typing `?lm`.

You probably meant to do something like:

```
myModel <- lm(selected.model,data = myDataFrame)
```

where `myDataFrame` is whatever you've called your source data frame. Then you would call `predict` on `myModel`.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed, all I needed was lm after the <-, I've done that for loads of other linear models earlier in my work I am just an idiot and forgot it here. Thanks so much!